# A negative number is converted too negative

Tags: php, format

```
<?php           
    function convertToHoursMins($total, $format = '%02d:%02d') {
        $hours = intval($total / 60);
        $minutes = ($total % 60);
        return sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes);
    } 
    echo convertToHoursMins($total, $format = '%02d:%02d');
?>
```

This solution works perfect (like many other solutions) when $total is positive.
When $total on the other hand is negative both $hours and $minutes gets negative like -hours:-minutes.
Every solution I have tried echoes the same output, and I am getting frustrated.
I really wood appreciate some help!

Comment: You forgot to tell us what do you expect with negative value.

Comment: Sorry, when negative $total (which is minutes) is converted, I expect -$hours:$minutes.

Comment: If you just want the mins as positive for display purposes you can set them as such with `$mins = ($mins<0 ? $mins * -1 : $mins);` to set to positive, if negative.

Comment: Work with absolute value, then prepend `-` if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of solutions is to work with absolute value of `$total` and prepend `-` if required:

```
function convertToHoursMins($total, $format = '%02d:%02d') 
{
    $absTotal = abs($total);
    $hours = intval($absTotal / 60);
    $minutes = ($absTotal % 60);
    return sprintf((0 <= $total ? '' : '-') . $format, $hours, $minutes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertToHoursMins($total, $format = '%02d:%02d') {
    $total = abs($total);
    $hours = intval($total / 60);
    $minutes = ($total % 60);
    return sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes);
}
```

Comment: And `-` is added where? or you haven't understood the question?

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: @u_mulder: his answer differs from the question's code.

Comment: Answer differs but does it __answer__ the question?